# How to create a custom format to webgrid column helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a custom `format` in my webgrid helper. I'm trying that way, but is not working.

```
    if (fieldType == FieldType.Currency && format == null)
        format = x => string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "$ {0}", x.ReductionValue);

    this.Columns.Add(new GridColumn()
    {
        ColumnName = columnName,
        Header = displayName,
        Format = format,
        Style = styleColumn,
        CanSort = canSort
    });
```

I need that result be:

`$ myValue` for example: `$ 1.000,00`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same doubt, when I was trying to format a column of a webgrid.

I did it like this, I think is the same that you want to do:

```
public void AddCurrencyColumn(Expression<Func<T, decimal?>> expression)
        {
            Func<T, decimal?> compiledExpression = expression.Compile();
            this.Columns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = "Id",
                Header = string.Empty,
                Format = (item) => string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "$ {0}", compiledExpression(item.Value)),
                Style = "currency-webgrid-column"
            });
        }
```

As you can see, I compiled the expression and then, used it with the model to get the property value.

If you want to do something more generic, replace the type `decimal?`for a generic type and verify it before to do what you want to do.

Maybe you already have resolved your problem, but, perhaps it may help somebody else.